# Storing and retrieving image from SQLite - blob

Tags: android, sqlite, bitmap

I am trying to show the user profile details in offline mode. The basic info such as Name,Image,Address,Email.

I've read about blob, and saved the image in byte array form in blob.

Now while retrieving I've converted the byte array to bitmap and it is null always. :(

**Code snippet :**

Image is picked from gallery on button click:

```
photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
            }
        });
```

To pick up image and convert it string and byte array:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
        try
        { 
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data)
            { 
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA }; 
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null); 
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close(); 
                String fileNameSegments[] = imgPath.split("/");
                fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1]; 
                BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
                options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 3;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath,options);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o); 
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 140; 
                int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
                int scale = 1;
                while (true) {
                    if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                            || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                        break;
                    }
                    width_tmp /= 2;
                    height_tmp /= 2;
                    scale *= 2;
                }

                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize = scale;

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2); 
                images.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath)); 
                images.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                ;

                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();

                encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT); 
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Now the basic details and the encoded string are sent to server to save in db.
On success am saving the same details in SQLite.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
        {
            dialog1.dismiss();
            if(code==200)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SuccessfulLogin.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish(); 

                DBhelper dbHelper = new DBhelper(Edit.this);
                Employee employee_One = new Employee(byte_arr,  name.getText().toString(), mobile.getText().toString(),address.getText().toString(),birth.getText().toString(),UserID);
//                Employee employee_One = new Employee(byte_arr,  name.getText().toString(), mobile.getText().toString(),address.getText().toString(),city.getText().toString(),birth.getText().toString(),UserID);
                dbHelper.open();
                dbHelper.insertEmpDetails(employee_One);
                dbHelper.close();
                dbHelper.open();
                employee_One = dbHelper.retriveEmpDetails();
                dbHelper.close();
                /*
                Log.e("Edit Profile Details", "Address --" + employee_One.getAddress() + "\n name " + employee_One.getName()
                        + "\n Image " + Arrays.toString(employee_One.getBitmap()) + " \n mobile--" + employee_One.getPhoneNumber()
                        + "\n DOB " + (employee_One.getBirth()) + " \n email--" + employee_One.getEmail());

                Log.e("Profile Values", "Address --" + address.getText().toString() + "\n name " +
                        name.getText().toString() + "\n Image " + Arrays.toString(byte_arr) + " \n mobile--" +mobile.getText().toString());
*/
                Log.e("byte_arr", "" + Arrays.toString(byte_arr));

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Details updated successfully..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
```

Am using the same byte array here.

Employee constructor:

```
public Employee(byte[] b, String n, String k, String a, String bt, String e)
    {
        bmp = b;
        Log.e("\nEmployee bmp", "" + Arrays.toString(this.bmp));
        name = n;
        _phone_number = k;
        _address = a; 
        _birth = bt;
        _email = e;
    }
```

Retrieving data in offline mode:

```
if(isNetworkAvailable())
        {
            new DisplayDetails().execute(); 
        }
        else
        {
            DBhelper dbHelper = new DBhelper(ViewProfile.this);

            dbHelper.open();
            employee_One = dbHelper.retriveEmpDetails();
            dbHelper.close();

            Log.e("Profile Details", "Address --" + employee_One.getAddress() + "\n name " +
                    employee_One.getName() + "\n Image " + Arrays.toString(employee_One.getBitmap()) + " \n mobile--" + employee_One.getPhoneNumber());

            name.setText(employee_One.getName());
            address.setText(employee_One.getAddress());
            mobile.setText(employee_One.getPhoneNumber());
            birth.setText(employee_One.getBirth());
            email.setText(employee_One.getEmail());
            byte[] outImage=employee_One.getBitmap();
            ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
            Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            Image.setImageBitmap(theImage);

            /*
            ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
            Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            Image.setImageBitmap(theImage);

            ************

            ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
            Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            Log.e("\nbitmap", "" + theImage +"\n outImage--" + Arrays.toString(outImage));

            ****************

            ByteArrayInputStream arrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(arrayInputStream);

            ******************

            int intByteCount = outImage.length;
            int[] intColors = new int[intByteCount / 3];
            int intWidth = 2;
            int intHeight = 2;
            final int intAlpha = 255;
            if ((intByteCount / 3) != (intWidth * intHeight)) {
                throw new ArrayStoreException();
            }
            for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < intByteCount - 2; intIndex = intIndex + 3) {
                intColors[intIndex / 3] = (intAlpha << 24) | (outImage[intIndex] << 16) | (outImage[intIndex + 1] << 8) | outImage[intIndex + 2];
            }
            Bitmap bmpImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(intColors, intWidth, intHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            */

        }
```

I've tried all the commented code.But **Failed**

Every time I get null in bitmap and image is not assigned to `ImageView`.
At the same time am not able to add more than 6 columns in my table.It is giving various errors if I try to add 7th column.

I don't understand where it is going wrong..

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

**LOG**

```
  Image array: [91, 45, 49, 44, 32, 45, 52, 48, 44, 32, 45, 49, 44, 32, 45, 51, 50, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 49, 54, 44, 32, 55, 52, 44, 32, 55, 48, 44, 32, 55, 51, 44, 32, 55, 48, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 45, 49, 44, 32, 45, 51, 55, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 54, 55, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 45, 49, 44, 32, 45, 51, 55, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 54, 55, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 45, 49, 44, 32, 45, 54, 52, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 49, 55, 44, 32, 56, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 45, 49, 48, 54, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 45, 53, 54, 44, 32, 51, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 51, 52, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 50, 44, 32, 49, 55, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 51, 44, 32, 49, 55, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 45, 49, 44, 32, 45, 54, 48, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 51, 49, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 53, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 50, 44, 32, 51, 44, 32, 52, 44, 32, 53, 44, 32, 54, 44, 32, 55, 44, 32, 56, 44, 32, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 44, 32, 49, 49, 44, 32, 45, 49, 44, 32, 45, 54, 48, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 45, 55, 53, 44, 32, 49, 54, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 50, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 51, 44, 32, 51, 44, 32, 50, 44, 32, 52, 44, 32, 51, 44, 32, 53, 44, 32, 53, 44, 32, 52, 44, 32, 52, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 49, 50, 53, 44, 32, 49, 44, 32, 50, 44, 32, 51, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 52, 44, 32, 49, 55, 44, 32, 53, 44, 32, 49, 56, 44, 32, 51, 51, 44, 32, 52, 57, 44, 32, 54, 53, 44, 32, 54, 44, 32, 49, 57, 44, 32, 56, 49, 44, 32, 57, 55, 44, 32, 55, 44, 32, 51, 52, 44, 32, 49, 49, 51, 44, 32, 50, 48, 44, 32, 53, 48, 44, 32, 45, 49, 50, 55, 44, 32, 45, 49, 49, 49, 44, 32, 45, 57, 53, 44, 32, 56, 44, 32, 51, 53, 44, 32, 54, 54, 44, 32, 45, 55, 57, 44, 32, 45, 54, 51, 44, 32, 50, 49, 44, 32, 56, 50, 44, 32, 45, 52, 55, 44, 32, 45, 49, 54, 44, 32, 51, 54, 44, 32, 53, 49, 44, 32, 57, 56, 44, 32, 49, 49, 52, 44, 32, 45, 49, 50, 54, 44, 32, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 44, 32, 50, 50, 44, 32, 50, 51, 44, 32, 50, 52, 44, 32, 50, 53, 44, 32, 50, 54, 44, 32, 51, 55, 44, 32, 51, 56, 44, 32, 51, 57, 44, 32, 52, 48, 44, 32, 52, 49, 44, 32, 52, 50, 44, 32, 53, 50, 44, 32, 53, 51, 44, 32, 53, 52, 44, 32, 53, 53, 44, 32, 53, 54, 44, 32, 53, 55, 44, 32, 53, 56, 44, 32, 54, 55, 44, 32, 54, 56, 44, 32, 54, 57, 44, 32, 55, 48, 44, 32, 55, 49, 44, 32, 55, 50, 44, 32, 55, 51, 44, 32, 55, 52, 44, 32, 56, 51, 44
 E/bitmap﹕ null
```

Comment: This is because there is a limit of 1MB to save any type of data in Db..instead of image..you can save image in sdcard..and then save the path of image  in db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In database 1 MB query limit is there to prevent nonsensical queries from bogging down the device.

http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html

Instead save your images in Sdcard...and in db store path to sdcard.

Comment: there is no such limit "in database", you can store data any size you want, ok there are some limits but way bigger: https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: if image is lost(if deleted)? then?

Comment: you can make them hidden ("using "dot" with the image name) so no onecould delete them

Comment: @pskink agreed there is no limit in db..it depend on memory..but there is a limit with the query..cursor..the amount of data your are fetching from db..

Comment: @MeenalSharma does the same happens with whatsapp?

Do they save the profile pic in local

Comment: yes..you can see the images in your sdcard..inside whats app-profile pictures folder

Comment: OK..Am following your answer..saved the image in hidden folder..now doing sql part..I'll tell you once am done with it..Thank u for showing some another way to do this

Comment: Gr8..glad to hear that :)

Comment: :) A query.. What if I don't store the path..Am saving the file name with the user name.and only 1 image is stored in that hidden folder.So while displaying I'll directly go to the path and get image

Comment: so,I can use that field for some other data. And y it is accepting only 6 columns?can we extend? @MeenalSharma

Comment: Gross misinterpretation of the docs.
As per the docs "For BLOBs smaller than 100KB, reads are faster when the BLOBs are stored directly in the database file. For BLOBs larger than 100KB, reads from a separate file are faster. "

Answer (score 0):

Replace decodeStream with decodeByteArray:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(theImage , 0, theImage.length);
```

Comment: @Prabs Do remember to replace **picture.length** to **theImage.length**, sorry I missed that out earlier on.

Comment: I've added the log..Again its null